# Pivot table with top N prodcts that appear in a sale - Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to make a pivot table of the following:
I have a database of the sales that a grosery store made in January, where in each sale there can be multiple products and the quantity purchased of these products in a specific sale can be varied, for example:

```
ID| Sell_ID |Product_ID| Product_qty| Price
1   4756818 Eggs    2   0.5
2   4756818 Tomato  1   0.6
3   4756816 Eggs    3   0.5
4   4756816 Onion   1   0.7
5   4756815 Cigarrets   1   8.7
6   4756815 Coke    1   1.95
7   4756813 Eggs    4   0.5
8   4756813 Tomato  1   0.6
9   4756721 Cigarrets   1   8.7
10  4756721 Coke    2   1.95
11  4756721 Soap    1   1.3
12  4756711 Chips   2   2.5
13  4756711 Coke    1   1.95
14  4756711 Cookies 1   1.5
15  1013667 Chips   2   2.5
16  1013667 Cigarrets   1   8.7
17  1013667 Coke    1   1.95
18  1013667 Popcorn 2   1.2
```

I would like to be able to choose the products that were sold the most and calculate the number of times that the other products were sold according to these "most sold products", and obtain a pivot table like the following:

```
    Eggs| Tomato| Onion| Cigarrets| Coke| Soap| Chips| Cookies| Popcorn
Coke    0   0   0   4   5   1   4   1   1
Eggs    9   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
Chips   0   0   0   2   4   0   4   2   2
```

I already tried to do something like this, but it only throws me NaN values:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df_january, index=['Prodct_id'], values=['Product_qty'], columns=['Product_id'], aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: Hi, I will be happy to provide an answer to you tomorrow. Pitifully I am feeling exhausted today, hopefully this resource will help you solve it. https://medium.com/@jihargifari/how-to-perform-market-basket-analysis-in-python-bd00b745b106

Comment: what's the basis for determining coke, eggs, chips as the most sold?

Comment: The Product_qty column